# Вывести PID процесса С++

Tags: c++, процесс

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как в программе, написанной на С++ вывести PID запускаемого процесса. ОС - Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что процесс должен вывести свой PID?
Если да, то так:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << getpid() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, все верно, спасибо